# Why is a dc voltage of 0.3v is applied in order to check the closedloop1 AC response?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, source

I have read the article related to current source “ opamp current source in simulation on prototype”. I wanted to know during simulation why a dc voltage of 0.3v is applied in order to check the closedloop1 AC response. Is there  any specific reason to choose 0.3v? I am attaching the link related to this question.
[Opamp current source stable in simulation but unstable on prototype](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387897/opamp-current-source-stable-in-simulation-but-unstable-on-prototype?rq=1)

[image: dc voltage added with ac frequency response]

Similarly I have also observed the same dc voltage of 0.3V with ac source to plot the bandwidth in the following thread.
The links are shown below:
<https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392662/current-source-with-unlimited-cap-drive-op-amp-oscillating >

Comment: That bias is needed to ensure the opamp is in its linear range.

Answer (score 0):

The 0.3 bias voltage sets the output current at 3 Amps.

Through the feedback that same voltage will appear across the 0.1 ohm current sense resistor.

The AC measurements could be performed at different output currents by changing that voltage. In particular the gm of the output FET will change with the output current and that will change the open loop gain and thus the AC loop characteristics.

Comment: Hi Kevin
Thank you very much for this clarification. 
If I have any further queries, would you mind if I asked you again?